# Como montar um regex para determinadas strings c#?

Tags: c#, regex

Como eu poderia montar um regex para uma string aleatória.
Por exemplo se eu fosse pegar todas as palavras que estivesse neste formato em uma string,

02ef6308-72da-491a-86b3-884a9e6bd959

Eu fiz assim, mas não deu certo para pegar este resultado. O que está errado?

Regex r = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}-");

Comment: Há mesmo este `-` no final?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usamos o regex para buscar padrões e não "strings aleatórias". Neste seu caso, parece que vc quer buscar por GUIDs.

Com a exceção de um `-` no final do padrão, o teu regex parece correto, mas poderia ser simplificado para `[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}`, uma vez que há 3 partes similares no meio.

Comment: Entendi como simplifica. Obrigado!

Comment: Se for mesmo um GUID, é melhor usar `[A-Fa-f0-9]` pra só considerar as letras de "A" a "F"

Comment: Verdade @hkotsubo, não havia me atentado a isso! Atualizei a resposta. Tks